Read OTP from SMS with browser Mobile And DeskTop
is it possible to achieve the same functionality using React in a mobile browser or on a laptop/desktop environment?
I have successfully implemented OTP (One-Time Password) retrieval in a native Android app using Kotlin. However,
Here's the Kotlin code I used for OTP retrieval in the native Android app:
val smsReceiverLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    onResult = { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
            // Get SMS message content
            val message = result.data!!.getStringExtra(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE)
            val oneTimeCode = parseOneTimeCode(message) // Create this method
            otp = oneTimeCode // Save this OTP to use somewhere else
            onOtpSubmit() // OPTIONAL (auto-submit the OTP)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "OTP retrieval failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
)


Yes, it's possible to read OTP using the WebOTP API in a web browser environment. Below is an example code snippet demonstrating how to achieve this using React:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if ("OTPCredential" in window) {
      const ac = new AbortController();
      navigator.credentials
        .get({
          otp: { transport: ["sms"] },
          signal: ac.signal,
        })
        .then((otp) => {
          setOtp(otp?.code);
          ac.abort();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          ac.abort();
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // Handle OTP input change here
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="Enter OTP Here........."
        value={otp}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Please note the following considerations:

The WebOTP API allows you to retrieve OTPs directly from SMS
messages. However, the format of the SMS must adhere to specific
guidelines outlined in the  official documentation.
For cross-device, please ensure that both the mobile device and
desktop/laptop are logged in with the same Google accounts and that
Google Chrome is the default browser on the mobile device.
Additionally, Chrome should be running in both the background and
foreground. You can find more details here.

Feel free to reach out if you have any further questions    or need clarification!

Demo App for testing :
step 1 :-   open this in mobile device : link
step 2 :-   send this sms to same mobile device
sms :-    Your OTP for authorisation: 123456. @myotptester.netlify.app #123456
